# How can I scrape a udp BitTorrent tracker in Java?

Tags: java, udp, bittorrent

I send a scrape packet, seeders, downloaders and leechers always return as 0.

Here is my initial connection and scraper code.

```
public void scrape() {
        for (final String infohash : infoHashes) {
            hashes += infohash;
        }
        outStream.writeByte(hashes.getBytes());
```

}

For example my output is

3617635676834215396
0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for (final String infohash : infoHashes) {
>     hashes += infohash;
> }
> outStream.writeByte(hashes.getBytes());
> ```

My guess is that you're using hex-encoded hashes. UDP scrapes expect them in their raw format.